# Compare elements of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I have two javascript array and I need to compare them. For example, suppose I have these two arrays:

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var array2 = ["4", "1", "3", "2"];
```

These arrays are equal in fact and I want to get `true` as a result of comparison. What is the best and fastest way for doing that?

Comment: Your array can have same value repeated ?

Comment: Yes, maybe they have some repeated value.

Comment: I sincerely hope that the downvotes below didn't come from you, OP.

Comment: No, I didn't down vote any answer.

Comment: Hmm, then normal index check will not work, we need to have the number of times a number is repeated. I have captured that in my solution, and time complexity is O(n), and Space complexity is also O(n)

Comment: @TechnoCrat.. OP's question is in JavaScript where we don't have any notion of lists and no `containsAll` method. You can see that in the related tags as well :)

Answer (score 4):

What you really have are two *sets*, not arrays, but unfortunately JavaScript does not provide any sort of "set" datatype. The easiest way to do this type of check is by using some sort of functional JavaScript library, such as lodash.

Using [lodash's `_.union` function](https://lodash.com/docs#union) makes this trivially easy.

```
function setsEqual(a, b) {
  var u = _.union(a, b);
  return u.length === a.length && u.length === b.length;
}
```

---

If you want to do this without external libraries, you can do so using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
function setsEqual(a, b) {
  return a.length === b.length
      && a.every(function (v) { return b.indexOf(v) !== -1; });
}
```

Comment: Until Js get some new functions to do this quickly, this is the fastest way in which you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way and fastest way to do this is using object which keep tracks the value of and its count. Then we can see if it exist in second array. Try this

```
function compare(arr1, arr2){
    var obj={}, len = arr1.length, i=0, isSame=true, prop;
    if(arr1.length === arr2.length){
        for(;i<len;i++){
            if(obj[arr1[i]]){
                obj[arr1[i]] = obj[arr1[i]]+1;
            } else{
                obj[arr1[i]] =1;
            }
        }
        i=0, len = arr2.length;
        for(;i<len;i++){
            if(obj[arr2[i]]){
                obj[arr2[i]] = obj[arr2[i]]-1;
            } else{
                isSame = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (prop in obj){
            if(obj[prop] > 0){
                isSame = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        isSame = false;
    }
    return isSame;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing matching elements until both elements are empty:

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "5"];
var array2 = ["1", "5", "2", "3", "4", "1"];
var isSame = false;
if(array1.length != array2.length)
    isSame = false;
else
{
    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i ++)
    {
        var removed = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j ++)
        {
            if(array2[j] == array1[i])
            {
                //  remove from array2
                array1.splice(i, 1);
                //  remove from array1
                array2.splice(j, 1);
                //  go back 1 for i
                removed = true;
                i --;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!removed)
            break;
}

    if(array1.length == 0 && array2.length == 0)
        isSame = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose that is a fastest approach but it can be useful for a little arrays with primitives

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
  var copyA = a.slice(),
      copyB = b.slice();

  if (a.length !== b.length) { return false; }
  return copyA.sort().toString() === copyB.sort().toString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Return status from function after comparing two array.

```js
arr1 = [101,12,13,10,4];
arr2 = [101,4,12,13,10];


function compareTwoArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.length === arr2.length && 
  arr1.sort().every((val, index)=> val === arr2.sort()[index]);
}  
console.log(compareTwoArray(arr1, arr2))
```